# Display of List obejct after button click in JSP of Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, buttonclick

I am implementing a web application in **spring mvc and jsp**.

I have **list of questions and answer options** in request or session attribute set by **controller**.

In **JSP** i want to iterate the list using previous and back **button**.

Do we can implement this by jstl for each, javascript or suggest me some other **better approach** :)

Comment: how is your list displayed? On what kind of control? Is there a relationship between the questions and answers

Comment: Hi @ThaSaleni,
1) My every single object in my list should be displayed at a time.
2) If back or next button is clicked the appropriate object should be displayed again.
3) Ya there is one to one mapping cardinality between questions and answers.

Comment: I still don't get how it is gonna be dispayed on your page, what kind of UI control